# Meaning of 過去形の動詞 ＋「[上]{うえ}で」

Tags: grammar, nuances

Lately, I've been wondering about the meaning of a past tense verb connected to 上で, like in the 3 examples below:

> 両親とよく相談した上で、留学することにした。
>
> 家を買う場合は、十分調べた上で、決めた方がいい。
>
> よく考えた上で、返事をするつもりだ。

What's the meaning of 過去形の動詞＋上で ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "after doing 〜".  Almost like `〜てから`.

> - 両親とよく相談した上で、留学することにした。　→　After discussing it with my parents, I decided that I'll study abroad.
> - 家を買う場合は、十分調べた上で、決めた方がいい。　→　When you buy a house, you should choose (it) after doing sufficient research.
> - よく考えた上で、返事をするつもりだ。　→　I intend to reply after careful consideration.

<strike>There is some other nuance I believe, but I'll have to look it up later.</strike>  The nuance to it is that the second action is performed based on the result of the first action (as @TokyoNagoya mentioned).  With `〜てから`, no such relationship is required, meaning that it simply indicates temporal order.  For example

> ○　昼食を食べてから銀行に行く　→　"I'll go to the bank after I eat lunch"　→　Going to the bank doesn't depend on me eating lunch; simply states the order of what I'm doing.
>   ?/×　昼食を食べた上で銀行に行く　→　It introduces a dependency for going to the bank on eating lunch.  Almost like "As a result of eating lunch, I'll go to the bank."  Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The nuance is, as the word 「上」 might suggest, that Action B should be performed "based upon" the result of Action A.

Comment: There's even the English construction, _"upon doing X..."_ of roughly the same meaning.  This requires the _-ing_ form of the verb so the past tense would be _"upon **having done** X..."_.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a supplement to the above answer & comment.

Your question was specific to ~た上で (so I won't expand unless you expand the question) but FYI there are other different uses of 〜上. I found the following sentence (from one the Soumatome-goi series) helpful to remember:

> 地図の上では近いのに
>
> 行ってみると
>
> 遠い上に、ひどい道だった
>
> よく調べた上で行けばよかった。
>
> On the map it looked close, but
>
> when I actually went there,
>
> it was far and the roads were bad.
>
> I should have checked before I went.