# What is the meaning of ta-form + 上で in this context?

Tags: grammar

> このうち、これまでに５回、パラリンピックに出場した競泳の成田真由美選手は、左手が不自由で、ふだんからエスカレーターの右側につかまって乗っていることを**紹介したうえで**「意識を変えることに費用はかかりません。障害のある人の立場にたって考えてほしい」と呼びかけました。([article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180623/k10011492721000.html?utm_int=news-life_contents_list-items_006))

According to the answers of this [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15190/meaning-of-%E9%81%8E%E5%8E%BB%E5%BD%A2%E3%81%AE%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E-%EF%BC%8B-%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%86%E3%81%88%E3%81%A7), "ta-form + 上で" means that the second action is performed based on the result of the first action.

If the writer had used てから, it would have meant : doing the 紹介 and then the 呼びかけ (without telling anything about the relation between them except that 紹介 is made before the 呼びかけ)

But the author uses 紹介した上で, so it means(according to the stack exchange post I linked before) that  the result of 紹介する is used to do the second action (呼びかける)

I don't understand what is the "result" of 紹介 and how this result is used in the 呼びかける.

According to me, the result of a presentation is the reaction of the public, so 呼びかける should be made according to the reaction of the public but it sounds odd because since the 呼びかけ tries to raise the awareness and convince the public,it would mean that the reaction of the public was negative.

I don't think it's the correct interpretation so my very question is:

**"ta-form + 上で" means that the second action is performed based on the result of the first action.
In the context of this article, what is the "result" of 紹介 and how is this result used in the 呼びかける ?**

Comment: http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/06/26/the-pattern-「〜上で」/

Comment: @Locksleyu I don't see which explanation is relevant in this case ? Because the one with a verb in past tense also talks about a second action made according to the result of the first action so it doesn't really tell me anything new ?

Comment: The answer in your link says it means "after doing 〜". It makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: @YuuichiTam Yes but just after it is said :"Almost like 〜てから.The nuance to it is that the second action is performed based on the result of the first action"

Comment: @Jirei I'm not sure (even with your desc) where in that passage you're exactly stumped. Could you tell us how you understand this part, say, in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have pointed out, understanding this ta-form + 上で expression is dependent on understanding what "result" is being referred to.
The result of 左手が不自由で、ふだんからエスカレーターの右側につかまって乗っていることを紹介する is that people are now **aware of the reason** she and others in similar situations have to be on one side of the escalator. So now that that reason has been announced publicly, she is asking that people be more aware of such situations, be considerate, etc.

Answer (score 2):

"ta-form + 上で" means basically "after doing". It has a nuance that a following sentence is on the premise for a sentence before 上で. That is the speaker emphasizes that a sentence before 上で is before a following sentence.

For example, 私は英語を勉強した上でアメリカに行きたい is almost the same as 私は英語を勉強した後でアメリカに行きたい or 私は英語を勉強してからアメリカに行きたい. However when you use 上で, it has the nuance like going to the U.S is on the premise for learning English.

As for your sentence, it means "After she introduced her trouble when she take an escalator, she appealed that she want people to think about things from  handicapped people's viewpoints". It was emphasized that introducing her trouble was before her appeal and her appeal was on the premise for it.